# Software Updater can't check for updates

Tags: 20.04, update-manager, asus, repository

I'm using an ASUS laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I want to update the system and some other software. When I opened it, it shows a message that interrupts the check: `Failed To Download Repository Information Check your Internet connection.` I'm sure that I'm connected to a stable network because everything still works fine, so how can I fix this?

Error message:

[image: Error Message]

System info:

[image: System info]

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have any broken repositories by `sudo apt update` and if there is any, click on 'settings' bellow the error and on the 'Other Software' tab deselect the broken repository and also select the best server for your region.
Run `sudo apt update` again and open software updater again. This worked fine for me.